# Remove duplicate SQL rows by looking at all columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have this table, where every column is a VARCHAR (or equivalent):

```
field001 field002 field003 field004 field005 .... field500
```

500 VARCHAR columns. No primary keys. And no column is guaranteed to be unique. So the only way to know for sure if two rows are the same is to compare the values of all columns.

(Yes, this should be in TheDailyWTF. No, it's not my fault. Bear with me here).

I inserted a duplicate set of rows by mistake, and I need to find them and remove them.

There's 12 million rows on this table, so I'd rather not recreate it.

However, I do know what rows were mistakenly inserted (I have the .sql file).

So I figured I'd create another table and load it with those. And then I'd do some sort of join that would compare all columns on both tables and then delete the rows that are equal from the first table. I tried a NATURAL JOIN as that looked promising, but nothing was returned.

What are my options?

I'm using Amazon Redshift (so PostgreSQL 8.4 if I recall), but I think this is a general SQL question.

Comment: Do you want to delete **all** duplicate rows or do you want to keep one of them?

Comment: As I said earlier in the post, I have the data, so it's fine if whatever query I run deletes all duplicate rows. I can just load the set again, once.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the whole row as a single record in Postgres (and thus I *think* in Redshift).

The following works in Postgres, and will keep one of the duplicates

```
delete from the_table
where ctid not in (select min(ctid)
                   from the_table
                   group by the_table); --<< Yes, the group by is correct!
```

**This is going to be slow!**

Grouping over so many columns and then deleting with a NOT IN will take quite some time. Especially if a lot of rows are going to be deleted.

---

If you want to delete **all** duplicate rows (not keeping any of them), you can use the following:

```
delete from the_table
where the_table in (select the_table
                    from the_table
                    group by the_table
                    having count(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to identify all the mistakenly inserted rows using CREATEXID.If you group by CREATEXID on your table as below and get the count you should be able to understand how many rows were inserted in your transaction and remove them using DELETE command.

```
SELECT CREATEXID,COUNT(1)
  FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: CREATEXID seems to be some sort of Netezza (?) SQL extension. Redshift is pretty much vanilla Postgres. Please reread my post and try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simplistic solution is to recreate the table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE my_temp_table (
    -- add column definitions here, just like the original table
);
INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM original_table;
DROP TABLE original_table;
ALTER TABLE my_temp_table RENAME TO original_table;
```

or even

```
CREATE TABLE my_temp_table AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM original_table;
DROP TABLE original_table;
ALTER TABLE my_temp_table RENAME TO original_table;
```

Comment: I have 12 million rows. I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

It is a trick but probably it helps.

Each row in the table containing the transaction ID in which it row was inserted/updated: [System Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-system-columns.html). It is `xmin` column. So using it you can to find the transaction ID in which you inserted the wrong data. Then just delete the rows using

```
delete from my_table where xmin = <the_wrong_transaction_id>;
```

PS: Be careful and try it on the some test table first.